# compiling qml in macOS kdb+/q (CFLAG?)

Tags: macos, kdb, q-lang

I have an issue with compiling qml in my macOS environment. I am not from IT background so I do not fully understand every detail in compiling C/C++ programs.

I have attempted to compile qml library on my macOS-- but I have been getting this error: 
'selecting C floating-point options... not found'

Due to above error, the configuration process terminates. 
From googling, I have figured that the default gcc compiler setting for macOS is different from those of linux/windows. Can anyone possible help me with what the issue could be? (i.e., what kind of programs / compilers should I install to somehow get 'CLFAG' environment variable defined?)

Thank you for help in advance.

Comment: one little issue i had.. my macOS is m64 and the kdb+ version that i had is a free 32-bit version, as i installed this at home. somehow during the ./configure process, mac was compiling qml in m64--which later resulted in having below error: ": mach-o, but wrong architecture"... So I just ended up manually changing the configure bash script so that it always compiles using -m32, not -m64. And it worked well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use gcc(not clang which is default on macOS).

```
brew install gcc
```

Then in qml folder

```
./configure CC=gcc-7
```

After that follow normal `make && make test && make install` instructions